# Libgdx cursor disappears after catched

Tags: java, libgdx

I set the mouse to be "catched" with

```
Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
```

but the cursor disappeared with this setting on.
I'm developing an isometric 2d rts game and I really need the cursor to be forced to stay inside the window but I also obviously need the cursor to be shown. 
I'm using a Tiled map to draw the map.

Comment: Why does the cursor need to stay inside the window?

Like what if the user wants to close or minimise the window?

Comment: @Fooble They can alt-tab or exit anytime they want. I just need an Age of Empires style setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a game where I draw a dot wherever/whenever the player touches down or touches up, if you catch the cursor it will disappear, it's intended behavior. 
 
To fix this you have to draw a mouse yourself using a `Texture`, `Sprite` or `TextureRegion`. Here's an example: 
**To draw the cursor:**

```
public class MyCursor {

    private TextureRegion cursor;
    private float x, y;

    public MyCursor(TextureRegion cursorRegion) {
        cursor = cursorRegion;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(cursor, x, y);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**To process input:**

```
public class MyInput extends InputAdapter {

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private MyCursor myCursor;

    public MyInput(OrthographicCamera camera, MyCursor myCursor) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.myCursor = myCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        Vector3 temp = camera.unproject(new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0));
        myCursor.setPosition(temp.x, temp.y);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Also don't forget to enable input:**

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        TextureRegion cursorRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture("myCursor.png"));
        MyCursor cursor = new MyCursor(cursorRegion);
        MyInput myInput = new MyInput(camera, cursor);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add myCursosr.render(spriteBatch) to the render loop and now it works!